# How to make cookies?

Tags: php, angularjs, cookies, ionic-framework

I created a connection to my database using this topic: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1005150/posting-data-from-ionic-app-to-php-server

I redirected my user to a menu after login.

I need to have some kind of session cookie on my PHP server side (the one that makes the queries to my database). This would allow me to be able to reuse the email and the password that the user entered during his connection. And not oblige him to inform him again. I have seen several solutions including SQLITE and LocalStorage, none of these two solutions work.

I also have another problem, on the side of my php server, I do all of my queries. I have one that is supposed to return the following table:

```
libDiscipline Note
physic        15
mathematic    12
chimi         11
```

that I retrieve in my controller using `$` scope. I can not display more than two first values which is physic and 15 but I want to display the others informations like `mathematic 12` and `chimi 11`.

This is my script php and my controller which he take the informations of my table.

[image: scriptphp]

and my controller is :

```
.controller('CompteCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state) {

  $scope.data = {};

  $scope.nextpage = function(){
    var link = (the link of the path to my script php ) ;

    $http.post(link, {usermail : "test@test.com" }).then(function (res){
      if(res.data != ""){
        $scope.informations = res.data;
      }
    });
  };
})
```

As you can see , the usermail will be my future cookie like `$_SESSION['email']`.

Comment: What error are you getting with localStorage? Why is not working? Are you tried this library? https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question description, avoid images of code as they are not searchable and harder to read. Also, focus your question on one thing. If you have multiple unrelated problems, please write a different question.

Comment: Thanks ! My real problem is cookie on my application. LocalStorage doesn't work ... so y try others solutions. I don't know if it was ionic1 .

Comment: I don't know why is not working , i try this tuto : https://medium.com/@petehouston/awesome-local-storage-for-ionic-with-ngstorage-c11c0284d658